# Android Studio resizes my Images when I import them

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, imageview

I need to add an image as an Activity Background so.

> I right clicked res folder > New > Image Asset

and I imported a picture under Launcher Icons category. But my pictures have been resized and the quality has been lost. Is there anyway of importing the original image and its quality without having to resize it through Android Studio?

Also, how would I reference it in my XML? I'm used to eclipse and what I usually do is:

```
android:src="@drawable/MyPicture"
```

ALSO, How would this affect screen sizes since I'm avoiding resizing? The original image size 900 x 678

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing them, as you said, under Launcher Icons category, which will automatically try to resize them to 48dp (and the respective px for the resolution density). You probably just want to navigate to your project and copy paste the image into the drawable folder and then refer to it as you mentioned in your question.

```
android:src="@drawable/MyPicture"
```

Your other option is to create different sized backgrounds and copy paste them into their respective drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, and drawable-xxxhdpi folders.

Android will try to scale your image to fit the screen unless you specify a `scaleType`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I'm trying to add an image that is 900x678 and when I add the ScaleType as centercrop it looks fine however I'm worried about the performance and other screen sizes. Since I'm not resizing, how will this affect my app?

Comment: @Earthling, I am not sure exactly how it will affect performance but I would try to decide whether you are also trying to cater this app to tablets and then choose a large enough suitable size for your image